# mysql query show only 1 result

Tags: php, mysql

i want to output the result based on todays date. 
the problem is, the output only show 1 result?

```
database report table:
id  |  r_amount | id_therapist | date | time | t_tanning | t_deep 

// this query works fine echoing all the result if i use while loop
$today = date('Y-m-d');
(1) $q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM report WHERE date='$today' ORDER BY date ASC")

// this query only show 1 output result?
(2) $q = $db->query("SELECT *, SUM(IF(t_tanning LIKE 'Pro Tan%', r_amount, 0)) AS totalProTan FROM report WHERE date='$today' ORDER BY date ASC")

while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
     // (1) echoing all result from database
     echo $r['r_amount'].'<br>';
     // (2) echoing only 1 result????
     echo $r['totalProTan'].'<br>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: you do realize we have **NO IDEA** what your db looks like or what is in it

Comment: @Neal sorry :) there is no need to show database table actually :( just query problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `date` field is of type `datetime`, you'll have to do something like

SELECT ... WHERE DATE(`date`)=CURDATE()

Notice that I'm using `curdate()` in the query. There's no need to generate the date value in PHP. MySQL is perfectly capable of doing that itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `GROUP BY` statement to the second SQL statement.

- you should group by the key of the elemnts you want to be shown in the end result

Comment: thanks i tried that one. but i want to show all the result not GROUP BY :)

Comment: @boyee007 then you are losing the effect of the `SUM` function here. either remove it or add a `GROUP BY` statement for your results to display more than 1 row

Comment: @boyee007 what are you trying to achieve here, maybe there is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

The use of the aggregate function SUM will result in a single result. You are asking the database to get all the rows then sum up a value and give you the value.

To see the result for many groups of values you have to add a group by clause.